# How to associate a shortcut key (hotkey) for my application in setup and deployment project.?

Tags: c#, shortcut, setup-deployment, hotkeys

I know how to add shortcut for my application in setup and deployment project, but the question is how to edit properties of that shortcut, especially hotkey (shortcut key; I can't find it in Visual Studio).

I googled for information but didn't got any information, of course I now how to create shortcuts using C# (Windows Script or VB), is there any way we can do it in setup and deployment project?

Thanks in advance.